# What's the difference between CD/DVD and USB image?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, iso

I am trying to install [NetBSD](https://www.netbsd.org/) on my laptop, but there are two download links for the amd64 architecture, one for `NetBSD-9.3-amd64-install.img.gz` and one for `NetBSD-9.3-amd64.iso`. FreeBSD does the same on its [download page](https://download.freebsd.org/releases/amd64/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/13.1/): there are both `*.iso` files and `*.img` files. The documentation says

> For the FreeBSD installer: formats include CD (disc1), DVD (dvd1), and network install (bootonly) sized ISO, plus regular and mini USB memory sticks.

It's 2023, and few people have CD/DVD on their laptop, so of course we want the `*.img` files, right? Not quite, because Ubuntu only provides `*.iso` files, and it works perfectly fine on USB sticks!

Questions:

- What's the difference between `*.img` and `*.iso` installers?
- Why does a CD/DVD image work on USB sticks?
- For a typical setting (a laptop/PC with a USB port but no CD/DVD drivers), which one should I use?

Comment: Both `.img` and `.iso` are raw disk formats. [Here's](https://nechstar.com/what-are-the-differences-between-iso-and-img-files/) an article discussing the issue. FWIW, I've never used `.img` files, only `.iso`, creating a bootable USBs with `dd`, Rufus or similar tools.

Comment: your question is not linux specific ... it belongs at https://superuser.com/questions

Comment: The name of this form is "unix and linux" so I would assume BSD counts and it doesn't have to be linux specific?

Comment: Obviously BSD questions belong here, but to re-iterate jsotola's comment the question isnt *NIX-specific. It's about differences between formats, and which one should be used in creating an installer. That actually is SuperUser stuff.

Comment: Actually, part of the question is how do you boot the installer for BSD, and what is the difference between img and iso for the BSD usb installer...  I can explain the difference for linux, but I have no idea what is in the bsd img file.  This is bsd specific.

Comment: @user10489 Could you explain the difference for Linux? I guess there won't be a huge difference between BSD and Linux.

Comment: For both BSD and Linux, the ISO is an ISO 9660 image (usable on cdrom, dvd, or usb) which has a very specific format for boot sequence that is standard to the iso9660 format and common for both OS's.  For linux, the img file is probably a ext4fs image with grub installed.  It might also have a partition table.   BSD will be something totally different.